# Two simple RewriteRule's in a row ... but strange result at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am turning crazy with this .htaccess :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L,R,QSA]

#--------------------------------------------------
# Format type management --------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html|json|xml)$ $1?_format_=$2 [QSA,NC]

#--------------------------------------------------
# Route management --------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

And I am trying to redirect :

```
http://mydomain/album/11.json
```

To

```
http://mydomain/index.php?_route_=album/11&_format_=json
```

Unfortunatley, I got this :

```
http://mydomain/index.php?_route_=album/11/11.json&_format_=json
```

I really dont understand what is wrong in theses tow rules and how comes this result ...

Any idea ?

Thx...

---

By the way, it works perfectly when I use this instead (add the second rule within the first one and add `L` flag), but this is not the way I want to achieve this :

```
(...)
#--------------------------------------------------
# Format type management --------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(html|json|xml)$ index.php?_format_=$2&_route_=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, I must say.

You need [`DPI` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi) to solve your problem (it needs to discard old path info)

> The DPI flag causes the PATH_INFO portion of the rewritten URI to be discarded.

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#--------------------------------------------------
# Format type management --------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(html|json|xml)$ $1?_format_=$2 [DPI,QSA,NC]

#--------------------------------------------------
# Route management --------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).+)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

**PS:** I have also made some minor changes in your rules to make regex better.

Comment: The DPI flag works great, you saved my day. I will have a serious look to your regex changes, I did not know the `?!` syntax. Thx.

Comment: Glad it worked out. `?!` is a negative lookahead which basically saves one `RewriteCond` from your earlier rule.